# Using Automapper to map an objects list

Tags: c#, automapper

I have an object (ProductModel) that has a nested list of images. I am trying to simplify the model (Product) that has this list as its property. I am using Automapper, but I can not seem to get the mapping configuration right. I viewed several other posts, but they seem to be a little different than what I am trying to achieve.

```
// Map to:
public class Product
{
    public List<Image> Images { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public string url { get; set; }
}


// Map from:
public class ProductModel
{
    public ImageSet ImageSet { get; set; }
}

public class ImageSet
{
    public List<ImageDetail> ImageDetails { get; set; }
}

public class ImageDetail
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you need to have the same name on the properties or create a mapping confiugration

Comment: Yes, it's the configuration that I'm trying to figure out because the objects can not change.

Comment: What version of automatter for EF Core or 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following configuration should work:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<ImageDetail, Image>();
    cfg.CreateMap<ProductModel, Product>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Images, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ImageSet.ImageDetails))
        ;
});
```